# Core Data many-to-many cascade archival (trashing) for last child object

Tags: core-data, many-to-many, cascade

Say I have `Project` and `Path`. `Project` has many paths (optional). `Paths` can belong to many projects (non-optional, min=1). When I archive the last `Project` associated to a `Path`, the `Path` should be archived, too. When the `Path` belongs to another active project, though, it should not be archived.

"Archival" equals setting the `archivedDate` property.

My naive approach is this: the persistent stack subscribes to Core Data notifications (not sure which, though), checks affected `Path` objects upon saving, and enforces the archival rule.

What would you do to implement "cascade" archival?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could simply override `setArchivedDate` in your `Project` class. There you can check the status of all the paths and archive accordingly, something like

```
-(void)setArchivedDate:(NSDate*)newValue {
   [self willChangeValueForKey:@"archivedDate"];
   [self setPrimitiveValue:newValue forKey:"archivedDate"];
   [self didChangeValueForKey:@"archivedDate"];

   for (Path *path in self.paths) {
      NSSet *activeProjects = [path.projects filteredSetUsingPredicate: 
         [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"archivedDate = nil"]];
      if (!activeProjects.count) {
         path.archivedDate = newValue;
      }
   }
}
```

PS: If you are using Swift, this is done in `didSet`.

Comment: I don't feel comfortable with the side-effects of setting the value. I guess a cleaning-up step would be to use KVO, for example. I like the `activeProjects` set filtering so far!

Comment: If logically setting the value has this effect, you **should** feel "comfortable" overriding the setter. This is a very common pattern in Core Data object graph management.